# How to use custom arrow using Arrow Left and Arrow Right - React Native slideshow

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using [this](https://github.com/haqiqiw/react-native-slideshow) plugin in react native, where i need to use custom arrow or text arrow just like `<` and `>` but i am not getting what the below type to use `arrowLeft` and `arrowRight` so, Is there any example for Arrow Left and Arrow Right

arrowLeft | object | optional | - | component arrow left

arrowRight | object | optional | - | component arrow right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you simple can pass any component in that i.e.

```
import Slideshow from 'react-native-slideshow';
import {Image} from 'react-native'

// ...

render() {
  return (
    <Slideshow 
      dataSource={[
        { url:'http://placeimg.com/640/480/any' },
        { url:'http://placeimg.com/640/480/any' },
        { url:'http://placeimg.com/640/480/any' }
    ]}
    arrowLeft={<Image source={require(PATH_TO_LEFT_ICON)}/>}
    arrowRight={<Image source={require(PATH_TO_RIGHT_ICON)}/>}/>
  );
}
```

**I used Image as the component, you can use whatever you want.
and now you are good to go.